# mongodb inner object to parent level

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I got result after aggregate like

```
{
  data: [
    {
      "_id": "61922aed85c74b2d1ef671bb",
      "employee": {
        "firstName": "fname",
        "lastName": "lname",
        "middleName": "mname"
      },
      "days": [
        {
          "_id": "61922aed85c74b2d1ef671be",
          "day": "2021-09-01T21:00:00.000Z",
          "data": {
            "hours": 0,
            "type": "OT",
            "_id": "61922aed85c74b2d1ef671bf",
            "updateDate": "2021-11-15T09:39:57.624Z"
          }
        },
        {
          "_id": "61922aed85c74b2d1ef671c0",
          "day": "2021-09-02T21:00:00.000Z",
          "data": {
            "hours": 0,
            "type": "OT",
            "_id": "61922aed85c74b2d1ef671c1",
            "updateDate": "2021-11-15T09:39:57.625Z"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible extract inner object of data of days array to the parent level.

From this

```
{
  "_id": "61922aed85c74b2d1ef671be",
  "day": "2021-09-01T21:00:00.000Z",
  "data": {
    "hours": 0,
    "type": "OT",
    "_id": "61922aed85c74b2d1ef671bf",
    "updateDate": "2021-11-15T09:39:57.624Z"
  }
}
```

to this

```
{
  "_id": "61922aed85c74b2d1ef671be",
  "day": "2021-09-01T21:00:00.000Z",
  "hours": 0,
  "type": "OT",
  "updateDate": "2021-11-15T09:39:57.624Z"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `$project` like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "day": 1,
      "hours": "$data.hours",
      "type": "$data.type",
      "updateDate": "$data.updateDate"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kFCNu4uxlmb)

Or to update values inside the array:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "employee": 1,
      "days": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$days",
          "as": "d",
          "in": {
            "_id": "$$d._id",
            "day": "$$d.day",
            "hours": "$$d.data.hours",
            "type": "$$d.data.type",
            "updateData": "$$d.data.updateDate"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pITBdjuybMN)

Comment: Thank you, second variant is better!